# How to connect two track lights

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I would like to connect two tracks ([Example H-Track](http://www.waclighting.com/product/h-track/)). Only the first track has access to a power source ([Connector used](http://www.waclighting.com/product/h-track-11/)). I know that there are adapters that which would connect two tracks directly to each other. However, the tracks are further apart and there is a wooden beam in-between them. 
Is it possible to connect the two tracks with two live-end adapter through wires (which I could snake through the attic space)? I was thinking of using two of these and connect them to each other: [live end connector](http://www.waclighting.com/product/h-track-13/)

Is this an entirely bad or even dangerous idea?

What are my options if the proposed idea is not recommended?

Thank you very much for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

### You should be able to do this

Given that a "live end connector" appears to be usable for feeding power into a section of lighting track, there appears to be no reason you cannot use two live ends and a section of NM (or whatever other Chapter 3 wiring method is suitable for your application) to connect two sections of lighting track together.

Comment: That was exactly my thought process as well. I wasn’t sure though if there is „something“ in the „live end connector“ preventing me from using it to feed another „live end connector“. Thank you very much for your help!